Dianoga still be a best option for Sitecore Image Optimization?
We are using Dianoga v5.3.0 for Sitecore Image Optimization. We have recently started reviewing to upgrade to the latest available version. We observed that the last version v6.1.0 (Sep 2022) was released 2 years back.
Could you please suggest, whether we should continue with Dianoga by upgrading to the latest available? OR any better Sitecore Image Optimization framework to think about?

Yes, Dianoga is still the best option as far as I know.
Why the latest version is released 2 years ago? It was adapted to match Sitecore 10 version and it does work with 10.X without any issues so there is no need to release new version with every single Sitecore release.

Yes, Dianoga is still a great choice for image optimization in Sitecore, especially if you want something easy to implement. It works smoothly with Sitecore, reducing image file sizes without losing quality, and integrates well with Sitecore's media library.
However, many modern CDNs like Cloudinary or other Image Scaling can handle image optimization directly at the delivery level, offering more advanced features.
If you’re happy with Dianoga and it meets your needs, updating to the latest version will keep you on track with improvements. But if you need more flexibility, exploring CDN-based solutions could be a good option.
It all depends on your project needs.
Hope this helps.
